# Looking for pre-built C++ source with editor

Tags: library, text-editor

I want to make a C++ MS Windows app. I'm looking for some sort of library I can include in my project and extend as necessary. Source code would be ideal, but a nice binary library would be acceptable.

It needs the following.

Suitable for including in a commercial product. A reasonable license fee is acceptable.

Works for MS Windows.

Compatible with C++ and Visual Studio.

Text editing with syntax coloring.

Simple spreadsheet display of data with minimal functionality, edit in the cells, resize the columns, and coloring. I don't need any other stuff like formulas or any of the complicated stuff that a typical spreadsheet program would have. Just need to be able to display data nicely in many columns (say no more than 30) and up to 20,000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) which is a GUI library with many components:

- Available as source code & pre-built
- Cross Platform - with a little care your application can be built for Windows, OS-X & Linux
- Compatible with multiple compilers including Visual Studio
- Has a liberal licence including the ability to sell applications that have been built with it
- Has a long history but is still being actively developed.
- Has comprehensive [documentation](https://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/) & a helpful community
- Includes a set of demo applications
- Has just about everything you are asking for
- Some screenshots of applications built with it are available [here](https://www.wxwidgets.org/about/screenshots/).
- Has bindings for other languages

PySpread, which is a non-traditional database that can support tens of millions of rows is written with wxPython *(the  Python bindings to wxWidgets).*

[image]

Answer (score -1):

"Crystal Reports" is the historical solution to making commercial quality reports. I suppose that it has its own configuration functionality and links to software like a .dll .

To develop a software that shows graphically rich reports would likely require loading up glossy images to lay over the output. Either that process or use black text on a white background with standard graphics.

Comment: That's not what the question asks for.

Comment: Crystal Reports is a software recommendation. It is pre-built and will link with C++.